# The significance of "word" in analyzing computer algorithms

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, clrs

I am reading ["Introduction to Algorithms"](http://highered.mcgraw-hill.com/sites/0070131511/), third edition. In there under the section "**Analyzing Algorithms**" it is written that:

> We also assume a limit on the size of each word of data. For example when working with inputs of size n, we typically assume that integers are represented by c lg n bits for some constant c>=1. We require c>=1 so that each word can hold the value of n, enabling us to index the individual input elements, and we restrict c to be a constant so that the word size doesn't grow arbitrarily.

What is the significance of the word "word" here? Is this a standard to represent data by "word"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They mean a *machine word*; basically the size of a processor register, or the "most natural size" of a piece of data for that machine. For a 32-bit machine, it's 32 bits; for a 64-bit machine, it is (not surprisingly) 64 bits.

Word size used to be somewhat more variable, as computer architectures evolved. If you look at [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) on word size, you'll see links to descriptions of 12-bit, 18-bit, 21-bit, 24-bit, 31-bit, 36-bit, 48-bit, and 60-bit hardware. I remember reading about a 72-bit machine once, although I can't find a reference right now.

Comment: What do you mean by "Word size used to be somewhat more variable, as computer architectures evolved."? can you shes some light ?

Comment: thanks for the clarification . +1 ..oops I do not have the privilige to give you a +1 yet ....

Answer (score 1):

A "Word" is typically a multi-byte integer value that matches the data register size of the underlying processor. Might be 16-bits on some systems, 32 on others, for example, although those aren't the only possibilities.

It was a data type in some languages at one point, but the lack of standardization in size caused a lot of portability issues.